# Catch Child Element within Parent Element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to catch the brother element using jQuery, i.e. child element within parent element?

**HTML**

```
<div class="fruit">
  <div class="apple"></div>
  <a class="mango"></a>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".apple").bind("mouseover", function () {
  $(this).parent.child(".mango").text("banana");
});
```

Comment: parent is a method, not a property: `.parent()`  http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Also, there is a `children()` method, but no `child()` method.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi oops that's true too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/5/
**Try this:**

```
 $(".apple").bind("mouseover", function () {
                $(this).siblings(".mango").text("banana");
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function:

```
$(".apple").bind("mouseover", function () {
  $(this).next().text("banana");
});
```

Comment: ".next()" is not the ultimate solution, it work in this case, but not if there are more than two elements and the element i want is far away

Comment: It works perfectly for the OP, in future, add such requirements into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Given you control a child and need to target a sibling, first reference the parent, and then start looking inside it.

Here, we first target parent by using `$(this).parent()`, and then we look inside that parent using `find(".mango")`:

```
$(".apple").bind("mouseover", function () {
  $(this).parent().find(".mango").text('banana');
});
```